# Is there a way to tell a method what value type it should return?

Tags: c#

I have a general-purpose method to help with different parts of a program in manipulating different types of arrays, and this method takes a `object[]` and returns a `object[]`. I quickly realized I'm not able to implicitly cast an `object[]`to a different type of array, though. Is there a way I could declare the method so that I could tell it what type to return, similarly to the way the the `List` class can be declared with any type of object?

I'm aware that I could use something like `Array.ConvertAll` to get the result, but I'd like to have the conversion dealt with in the method itself.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. A short code showing what you want is more valuable than describing.

Comment: You are talking about a specific feature, [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/), but not in same sense you have used the word "generic" in your question.

Comment: You are asking about generics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

Comment: "generic method" as in "C# generics" or "some not very specific method (just really a method)"? I'd recommend [edit] post to clarify that. Be careful using "generic" in C# questions as it usually relates to generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing because you use the word "generic" but talk about an array of objects (`object[]`). Generic is a language feature in .NET, which allow you to use a type as a parameter to e.g. a method.

Ironically, it sounds like generics is exactly what you're looking for, so let's go through the basics. 
You can create a generic method like this:

```
T[] Manipulate<T>(T[] input) 
{
     // Do manipulation of array here
}
```

See the special `<T>`? `T` is a type parameter to the method. You would be able to call the method with an array of any type:

```
var arr = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] result = Manipulate<int>(arr); // Actually, the <int> is not necessary in this case, since the compiler infers the type from the input
```

Since you give the method an integer array, the result of the method will also be an integer array (since you specified `T[]` as the return type).

I recommend reading some of the MSDN documentation on generics:

[Introduction to Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/introduction-to-generics)